# I was learning ssh using parakimo and recieved an error after following the video

Tags: python

What does this error mean and how can I solve it
TypeError: set_missing_host_key_policy() missing 1 required positional argument: 'policy'

```
def file_transfer():
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient # creates the ssh client
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy()) # adds to known list to avoid yes/no confirmation
hostname_input = str(input('enter hostname:'))
username_input = str(input('enter username:'))
password_input = str(input('enter passcode:'))
port_number_input = str(input('enter port number :'))
ssh.connect(hostname=hostname_input,username=username_input,password=password_input,port=port_number_input) # default port number is 22 for ssh
ssh.close()
```

Comment: The preceding line `ssh = paramiko.SSHClient` is wrong. You need the `()` on the end; it should be `ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()`

Comment: ...because you didn't do that, `ssh` points to the class itself instead of an instance of the class, so you don't have `self` implicit on `ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy`, hence your error, because the result of `paramiko.AutoAddPolicy()` is going into the `self` slot (which would be implicit if you had an instance instead of going directly to the class) instead of the `policy` slot.

Comment: (consequently, voting to close as caused-by-a-typo).